# Fancybox shows no content in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, fancybox-2

I have a simple page set up using fancybox to show a login form [here](http://efcworld.de/test/fbox.html). It works in all major browsers, except IE9. What is weird is that it works on my local webserver in IE9 without a problem, but on the online page it shows no content.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: what about closing the `<html>` tag? ... also, try editing your document encoding UTF-8 without BOM and force the upload as binary http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://efcworld.de/test/fbox.html

Comment: Your comment set me on the right track. The problem was, that my web server was sending charset=none in the response header. Using "AddDefaultCharset UTF-8" in my .htaccess fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just put your login.html, Basic HTML tags needs on the page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div>
<form action="#" method="post" id="login" class="overlay">
  <h1>Login</h1>
  <div id="username-password-group" class="control-group">
    <label for="username" class="control-label">Benutzername:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="input-xlarge" />
    <label for="password" class="control-label">Passwort:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="input-xlarge" />
  </div>
  <label for="remember-me" class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" name="rememberMe" class="inline"/>
    Eingeloggt bleiben
  </label>
  <input type="submit" value="Einloggen" class="btn btn-success" />
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

IE doesn't render the page without the basic HTML tags

Comment: i have worked around your code in my localhost, it is working fine in IE9

Comment: I just updated the example with your suggestion. It's still not working. On my localhost, everything works fine, too, but not on the online version.

Comment: try to update the login.html as well as in your live server too

Comment: i have used Jquery and css files located in your server so it will work in your server too

Comment: I did update the live server, not working. I don't know what causes this. My localhost uses the exact same code and it works there.